# SCons libraries and sub-libraries

Tags: c++, c, build, build-process, scons

I have a hierarchical build system based on SCons. I have a root SConstruct that calls into a SConscript that builds a shared library and then into a different SConscript that builds an executable that depends on the shared library.

So here's my question: my understanding of shared libraries on linux is that when you want to do the final `ld` link for the executable that will be using the shared lib, the shared lib has to be included on the executable's `ld` command line as a source to reference it (unless it's in a standard location in which case the `-l` option works).

So here's something like what my SCons files look like:

=== rootdir/SConstruct

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
shared_lib = SConscript('foolib/SConscript')
env.Append( LIBS=[shared_lib] )
executable = SConscript('barexec/SConscript')
```

=== rootdir/foolib/SConscript

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
env.Append(CPPPATH=Glob('inc'))
penv = env.Clone()
penv.Append(CPPPATH=Glob('internal/inc'))
lib = penv.SharedLibrary( 'foo', source=['foo.c', 'morefoo.c']
Return("lib")
```

=== rootdir/barexec/SConscript

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
exe = env.Program( 'bar', source=['main.c', 'bar.c', 'rod.c'] )
Return("exe")
```

So the hitch here is this line:

```
env.Append( LIBS=[shared_lib] )
```

This would be a great way to add generated libraries to the command line for any other libs that need them, EXCEPT that because SCons is doing a two-pass run through the SConscripts (first to generate it's dependency tree, then to do the work), `rootdir/foolib/libfoo.so` winds up on the command line for ALL products, EVEN `libfoo.so` itself:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Werror -o libfoo.so foo.o morefoo.o libfoo.so
```

So how is this best done with SCons? For now I've resorted to this hack:

=== rootdir/SConstruct

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
shared_lib = SConscript('foolib/SConscript')
env['shared_lib'] = shared_lib
executable = SConscript('barexec/SConscript')
```

...

=== rootdir/barexec/SConscript

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
exe = env.Program( 'bar', source=['main.c', 'bar.c', 'rod.c'] + env['shared_lib'] )
Return("exe")
```

Is there a more SCons-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You should allow the shared libraries to be found by the build.

Look for the `LIBPATH` and `RPATH` variables in the `SCons` documentation; these are the "Scons-y" way to set up search paths so that any generated `-l` options find libraries properly.

Having mentioned the above, here's what you *should* see `gcc` do based on the setup of SCons (and if it doesn't, you may have to do it manually).

The `-l` option always finds shared libraries provided that you also give the compiler the location of the library.  There are two times this is needed: at compile time (`-L` option) and at runtime (`-rpath` generated linker option).

The `LIBPATH` SCons setup should generate something that looks like `-L/some/directory/path` for the compile-time search path.

The `RPATH` SCons setup should generate a linker option to *embed* a search path; e.g. `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,\$ORIGIN/../lib` would embed a search path that searches relative to the executable so that executables placed in `bin` search in the parallel `lib` directory of the installation.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but doesn't this subvert SCons' dependency checking? If I add LIBS=foo to the bar program environment, then SCons won't necessarily know where gcc is getting libfoo.so (could be my project, could be /usr/lib or whatever as far as SCons knows), and won't detect the dependency between libfoo.so and barexec. I'd have to hack a dependency between foo and bar with env.Depends() wouldn't I?

Comment: @TedMiddleton, you have to tell SCons which libraries an executable needs (via the LIBS construction env), and where they are (via the LIBPATH construction env), then the dependency tree is created based on this. SCons will indeed know about them since it has these variables, which it subsequently passes to gcc or whichever compiler. And you will not need to hack any dependencies with the env.Depends() function. Try it and you'll see :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to organize your SConsctruct/SConscript files. Usually with Hierarchical builds you should share the env with the rest of the sub-directories. Notice that I cloned the main env in the barexec directory as well, so that the foolib is only used to link that binary.

=== rootdir/SConstruct

```
import os

env=DefaultEnvironment()

subdirs = [
    'foolib',
    'barexec'
]

# The exports attribute allows you to pass variables to the subdir SConscripts
for dir in subdirs:
    SConscript( os.path.join(dir, 'SConscript'), exports = ['env'])
```

=== rootdir/foolib/SConscript

```
# inports the env created in the root SConstruct
#
# Any changes made to 'env' here will be reflected in
# the root/SConstruct and in the barexec/SConscript
#
Import('env')

# Adding this 'inc' dir to the include path for all users of this 'env'
env.Append(CPPPATH=Glob('inc'))

penv = env.Clone()
# Adding this include only for targets built with penv
penv.Append(CPPPATH=Glob('internal/inc'))
penv.SharedLibrary( 'foo', source=['foo.c', 'morefoo.c'])
```

=== rootdir/barexec/SConscript

```
Import('env')

clonedEnv = env.Clone()

# The foo lib will only be used for targets compiled with the clonedEnv env
# Notice that specifying '#' in a path means relative to the root SConstruct
# for each [item] in LIBS, you will get -llib on the compilation line
# for each [item] in LIBPATH, you will get -Lpath on the compilation line
clonedEnv.Append(LIBS=['foo'], LIBPATH=['#foolib'])

clonedEnv.Program( 'bar', source=['main.c', 'bar.c', 'rod.c'] )
```

Comment: Something I discovered playing around with this after asking just this question is that DefaultEnvironment() accesses a global variable across SConscripts and sub-SConscripts, so unless you want to pass down a different environment, Import() and Export() aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: Also, see my comment above to Kevin Grant about LIBS=foo - does SCons detect the build dependency between libfoo.so and barexec if you do this?

Comment: @TedMiddleton, I do this sort of env cloning in my build system. The different environments are indeed isolated with respect to their variables etc, but the targets (libfoo.so and barexec) are still "detected" doing it this way. Im not certain, but I think the targets are global, they must be for this to work, and it does indeed work :)

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Brady decision i use static/global variables to store targets name and path. It's allow me more control over build.

```
# site_scons/project.py
class Project:
  APP1_NAME = "app1_name"
  APP2_NAME = "app2_name"
  MYLIB1_NAME = "mylib1_name"
  # etc
  APP_PATH = "#build/$BuildMode/bin" # BuildMode - commonly in my projects debug or release, `#` - root of project dir
  LIB_PATH = "#build/$BuildMode/lib"
  @staticmethod
  def appPath(name) :
     return os.path.join(APP_PATH, name)
  @staticmethod
  def libPath(name) :
     return os.path.join(LIB_PATH, name)
```

Define targets:

```
from project import Project
...
env.SharedLibrary(Project.libPath(Project.MYLIB1_NAME), source=['foo.c', 'morefoo.c'])
```

Application:

```
from project import Project
...
env.Append(LIBPATH = [Project.LIB_PATH])
env.Append(LIBS = [Project.MYLIB1_NAME])
env.Program(Project.appPath(Project.MYAPP1_NAME), source=[...])
```

In my projects it works fine, scons automatically find depends of library without any additional commands. And if i want to change name of library i just change my Project class.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that Brady's answer doesn't address is how to get correct library paths when building out-of-source using variant dirs. Here's a very similar approach that builds two different variants:

`SConstruct`

```
# Common environment for all build modes.
common = Environment(CCFLAGS=["-Wall"], CPPPATH=["#foolib/inc"])

# Build-mode specific environments.
debug = common.Clone()
debug.Append(CCFLAGS=["-O0"])
release = common.Clone()
release.Append(CCFLAGS=["-O"], CPPDEFINES=["NDEBUG"])

# Run all builds.
SConscript("SConscript", exports={"env": debug}, variant_dir="debug")
SConscript("SConscript", exports={"env": release}, variant_dir="release")
```

- The `#` in the value for `CPPPATH` makes the include path relative to the project root instead of the variant dir.

`SConscript`

```
Import("env")

subdirs=["barexec", "foolib"]
senv = env.Clone(FOOLIBDIR=Dir("foolib"))
SConscript(dirs=subdirs, exports={"env": senv})
```

- This root-level `SConscript` is required to build the subdirectories in each `variant_dir`.
- By using the function `Dir()` when setting `FOOLIBDIR`, the library's variant build directory is resolved relative to this file rather than where it's used.

`foolib/SConscript`

```
Import("env")

penv = env.Clone()
penv.Append(CPPPATH=["internal/inc"])
penv.SharedLibrary("foo", source=["foo.c", "morefoo.c"])
```

- It's important to clone the environment before making any changes to avoid affecting other directories.

`barexec/SConscript`

```
Import("env")

clonedEnv = env.Clone()
clonedEnv.Append(LIBPATH=["$FOOLIBDIR"], LIBS=["foo"])
clonedEnv.Program("bar", source=["main.c", "bar.c", "rod.c"])
```

- The library's variant build dir is added to `LIBPATH` so both SCons *and* the linker can find the correct library.
- Adding `"foo"` to `LIBS` informs SCons that `barexec` depends on `foolib` which must be built first, and adds the library to the linker command line.
- `$FOOLIBDIR` should only be added to `LIBPATH` when `"foo"` is also added to `LIBS` – if not, `barexec` might be built before `foolib`, resulting in linker errors because the specified library path does not (yet) exist.

Comment: $LIBPATH shouldn't be evaluated until the dependencies are walked (after all SConscript/SConstruct evaluation). So the order of barexec and foolib shouldn't matter.

Comment: @bdbaddog I also expected the order of subdirectories to be irrelevant, but in fact when I switch the order in the example above, the linker is invoked without the `-L` switch (SCons 3.0.1) – do you have any idea why that's the case? (I just fixed some other errors in my initial answer)

Comment: Add print("LIBPATH=%s"%clonedEnv['LIBPATH']) and paste the output above. (Right after your Append(LIBPATH..))

Comment: @bdbaddog it prints `LIBPATH=['$FOOLIBDIR']` in both cases – but I noticed something else: when `foolib` is before `barexec` and I use `--debug=tree`, I see a dependency `.` → `debug` → `debug/barexec` → `debug/barexec/bar` → `debug/foolib/libfoo.dylib`. When I change the order, `foolib` is missing from `barexec`'s dependencies! As a result, SCons builds `foolib` after `barexec` and `$FOOLIBDIR` is only set after `barexec` has been built. What's the correct solution for this?

Comment: Not possible. FOOLIBDIR is set before anything is built. When you say env.Object('source.c'), it is not built.  You are telling SCons to do that and implicitly that source.o depends on source.c. (For example.) . See example repo: https://github.com/bdbaddog/so-11571577 and specifically logs: https://github.com/bdbaddog/so-11571577/blob/master/BUILD.log and https://github.com/bdbaddog/so-11571577/blob/master/TREE.log

Comment: @bdbaddog wow, thanks for all your effort! Except for the difference between `.so` and `.dylib` because I'm on macOS I get exactly the same log (see my first commit). However, when I change the order of `barexec` and `foolib`, I get the logs shown in my repo at https://github.com/jkuebart/so-11571577/

Comment: Ahh.. The issue is your env.Clone()'s in the subdir SConscripts. Specifically barexec's.  See latest push to github.  So if you have barexec's SConscript first it Clones() the imported env before FOOLIBDIR is set in the "global" env which is passed around.  So when it's actually evaluated there is no FOOLIBDIR in the cloned "clonedEnv".  In these examples no need to clone. You can specialize LIBPATH and LIBS in the builder call.

Comment: Good to bring issues like this to the users mailing list https://scons.org/lists.html or the discord server https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy or IRC channel (#scons on freenode)

Comment: Great, that sheds some light on what was happening, thanks a lot! Specifying in the builder call doesn't solve all my problems because in general I do have existing values that I'd like to append to. But at least now I know what the problem was and can try coming up with a new solution. For a larger example where I use this method, see https://gitlab.com/jkuebart/aoc/

Comment: you can do something like env.mybuilder(target,source,SOME_VAR="$SOME_VAR more stuff")

Comment: Unfortunately, "$SOME_VAR more stuff" doesn't really work for me – when $SOME_VAR is empty, the resulting value starts with a blank. It would be nice if there was a nicer way to write `env.get("SOME_VAR", []) + ["more", "stuff"]`.