# SCons: When adding a Node to the LIBS variable, how do I make it use just the file without the directory?

Tags: scons

I have SCons code in which I am using SConscripts to build different directories separately.  In my `Src` directory, my SConscript builds a shared library, and then returns the resulting Node as the Python variable `libMyLibrary`.  I typically use the `install` option to copy this library to a directory that is on my system's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (I'm using OpenSUSE).

So far, so good.  Now, in another directory, `Src/Test`, another SConscript imports `libMyLibrary` and builds some Programs using code like this:

```
env.Program('myProgram', 'myProgram.cpp', LIBS=[env['LIBS'], libMyLibrary])
```

The program then gets installed to my local `bin` folder.  This code does track the library dependency and build the program, but the problem is that since the library is in a sub-directory (`Src`), that sub-directory gets included in the linker command.  Here is an abbreviated example of the linker command that SCons generates:

```
g++ -o Src/Test/myProgram Src/Test/myProgram.o Src/libMyLibrary.so
```

I believe this happens because the Node,`libMyLibrary`, is essentially a path.  The problem is that when I try to run the program, it is not looking for `libMyLibrary.so` in my library folder, but rather `Src/libMyLibrary.so`, and of course it doesn't find it.

I do NOT want the libraries I build to be installed in sub-directories of my install folder.

I already add the `Src` folder to `LIBPATH`, so SCons adds the `-LSrc` option to the linker command, but that doesn't solve the problem.  My preference would be that when I add a Node, the path should automatically get parsed out to add the appropriate `-L` and `-l` options.

I know that I can get around this problem by adding the string `'MyLibrary'` to the `LIBS` variable instead of the `libMyLibrary` Node, but then I have to explicitly tell SCons that each Program `Depends()` on `libMyLibrary`.  It seems very inefficient to short-circuit SCons's built-in dependency tracking this way.  Does anyone know the correct, SCons-y way to do this?

Comment: This looks convoluted, you shouldn't have to return the created Nodes from one SConstruct to the other. Can you possibly show us a "*minimal working example*" (MWE), or at least give a code snippet of how you set LIBPATH? Did you have a read of the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), chap 14 "*Hierarchical Builds*" yet?

Comment: @dirkbaechle I have read almost the entire UserGuide, including the section you mentioned.  It does not address my question.  I typically add paths to LIBPATH using something like `env.AppendUnique(LIBPATH='Src')`, but the LIBPATH is not the problem.  The problem, as I said, is that SCons puts the entire Node path into the linker command, like `Src/libMyLibrary.so` instead of using something like `-LSrc -lMyLibrary` or at least giving me that option.  Since I am not installing libMyLibrary.so into a subdirectory `Src`, it doesn't know how to find it at runtime.

Comment: You are talking about "runtime"...is this a problem with the build itself, or do you try to use SCons to run the created program afterwards (e.g. for testing purposes)? I mentioned chap 14 "*Hierarchical Builds*" because it states that "...unlike standard recursive use of Make, SCons stays in the top-level directory ...". This is one of SCons' features and it's not possible to work around it, so if you ask for the SCons-y way it would probably mean restructuring your build. For this, it would be helpful to have a "*minimal working example*" to play with.

Comment: @dirkbaechle I am not using SCons to run the program afterwards. It builds just fine because that library is present at that location in my repo. However, for runtime use, I install the library directly into a path on my system's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and the executable into my system's `PATH`. When it tries to dynamically link at runtime, it is not looking just for `libMyLibrary.so` within my system's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Rather, it is looking for `Src/libMyLibrary.so` and it doesn't find it. Does that make sense? If you might have a more SCons-y solution, I will put in the effort to make a MWE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm referring to your latest comment: It looks to me as if this is not really a SCons problem, but more a general linker question (XY problem). Are you perhaps simply searching for `RPATH`? Please also check this old SO question: [scons executable + shared library in project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564078/scons-executable-shared-library-in-project-directory)

Comment: I mean, my question is very simple. Is there an accepted SCons way to add a Node to the LIBS variable such that SCons will simply add the library flag `-lMyLibrary` to the linker command, instead of adding the entire Node path `Src/libMyLibrary.so`? I know exactly why the executable is not dynamically linking at runtime. It is because of the linker command that SCons generates, which I quoted in my question. I can get around it (see my question's last paragraph), but I'd prefer not to short-circuit SCons's dependency tracking.

Comment: Also, I know about RPATH, but it seems silly to use RPATH when I am installing the library in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: In the last paragraph of your question you claim: "I know that I can get around this problem by adding the string 'MyLibrary' to the LIBS variable instead of the libMyLibrary Node, but then I have to explicitly tell SCons that each Program Depends() on libMyLibrary.", but this would be the SCons-y way to do things. If this breaks your dependencies something is wrong, please provide a MWE demonstrating this single problem "missing dependencies when adding string to LIB" only. You might also want to subscribe to our User mailing list at scons-users@scons.org (see http://scons.org/lists.html).

Comment: If that is the SCons-y way to do things, then I'll accept it and move on.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Ah, were you saying I should try adding the string to LIBS only?  I have tried that, and SCons will sometimes build the library first, and sometimes not.  The `Depends()` statement is required to make SCons reliably build the library first.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant...sorry, not a native speaker here. ;) You can check the dependencies SCons found with the "`--tree=derived`" option (or use "`--tree=all`"). Please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571577/scons-libraries-and-sub-libraries , and come to our User mailing list.